# AggregateException not caught by Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, task, wait, aggregateexception

I'm trying to catch an NullReferenceException which is going to be thrown by Task.Factory.StartNew method. I think it should be caught by 'try' statement with task.Wait() method. 
I also referred to [Why is this exception not caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051187/exception-is-not-caught-aggregateexception-unhandled), but have no idea. Would you share your wisdom?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Csharp_study
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task my_task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw null; });
            try
            {
                my_task.Wait();
            }

            catch (AggregateException exc)
            {
                exc.Handle((x) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(exc.InnerException.Message);
                        return true;
                    });
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to VS's debugger and not your code.

If you're in debug mode and have **Just My Code** enabled (which is the default setting for most languages), turning it off should do the trick.

To disable the Just My Code feature, go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General and uncheck Just My Code checkbox.

If you're wondering what enabling Just My Code feature does, here's a excerpt from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Debugger.General);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1)&rd=true).

> Enable Just My Code
>   When this feature is enabled, the debugger
>   displays and steps into user code ("My Code") only, ignoring system
>   code and other code that is optimized or that does not have debugging
>   symbols.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I found the answer 3 months ago by myself as I made a comment at below one. But I couldn't find a way to close the question. So I'm marking yours as the one. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle exception for a task , check if it is faulted. If it is not faulted continue with execution.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task my_task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw null; });

            my_task.ContinueWith(x =>
            {

                if (my_task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(my_task.Exception.Message);

                }
                else {
                    //Continue with Execution
                }
            });
        }
```

And the `return true;` is invalid in this case as method does not have a return type.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your solution. This makes sense, but is there any other way I can handle the exception? like using conventional exception handling statement.  I'm also referring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx), but it also can catch the exception with Task.wait().

Comment: Continuing from above, I also tried your solution, but still getting same exception saying 'Unhandled', and also it looks the code is not handling the exception.

Comment: When working with tasks you have to check the state if it is faulted and the code above just works fine. Do you have the complete code?

Comment: @Simons/ Thanks for your help. Above one is a whole code. I tested that code on 2 PC with 2 different environments. / VS2010 + .NET 4.0 / VS2015 + .NET4.6 /

Comment: Solution found:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865523/why-cant-i-catch-an-exception-from-async-code
I'm closing this question.